# How to convert bytes type to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, byte

I have a **bytes** type object like this:

```
b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"
```

I need to get proper python dictionary from the above bytes type object using python code.

```
string = b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"
d = dict(toks.split(":") for toks in string.split(",") if toks)
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
------> d = dict(toks.split(":") for toks in string.split(",") if toks)
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

Comment: No need to make you own dictionary parser.  Send the string to [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: The code you've posted here does not raise that exception. In fact, it does almost what you say you want it to do (modulo some mistakes in dealing with quote characters—e.g., you're going to end up with a key like `" 'two'"` instead of `"two"`).

Comment: Meanwhile, where did this input come from? Taking the `repr` of a Python dict and `encode`-ing it to UTF-8 is really not a good way to store data that you want to load back in later. Much better to use something like JSON or Pickle.

Comment: @Aran-Fey bytes is different with strings

Answer (score 57, accepted):

All you need is `ast.literal_eval`. Nothing fancier than that. No reason to mess with JSON unless you are specifically using non-Python dict syntax in your string.

```
# python3
import ast
byte_str = b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"
dict_str = byte_str.decode("UTF-8")
mydata = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)
print(repr(mydata))
```

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary). It also details how `ast.literal_eval` is safer than `eval`.

Comment: seems need extra decode.
error log:
raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"

Answer (score 140):

I think a decode is also required to get a proper dict.

```
a= b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"
ast.literal_eval(a.decode('utf-8'))
**Output:** {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

The accepted answer yields

```
a= b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"
ast.literal_eval(repr(a))
**output:**  b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"
```

The literal_eval hasn't done that properly with many of my code so I personally prefer to use json module for this

```
import json
a= b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"
json.loads(a.decode('utf-8'))
**Output:** {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

Answer (score 20):

You could try like this:

```
import json
import ast

a= b"{'one': 1, 'two': 2}"
print(json.loads(a.decode("utf-8").replace("'",'"')))

print(ast.literal_eval(a.decode("utf-8")))
```

There are the doc of module:

1.[ast doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

2.[json doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Base64 library to convert string dictionary to bytes, and although you can convert bytes result to a dictionary using json library. Try this below sample code.

```
import base64
import json


input_dict = {'var1' : 0, 'var2' : 'some string', 'var1' : ['listitem1','listitem2',5]}

message = str(input_dict)
ascii_message = message.encode('ascii')
output_byte = base64.b64encode(ascii_message)

msg_bytes = base64.b64decode(output_byte)
ascii_msg = msg_bytes.decode('ascii')
# Json library convert stirng dictionary to real dictionary type.
# Double quotes is standard format for json
ascii_msg = ascii_msg.replace("'", "\"")
output_dict = json.loads(ascii_msg) # convert string dictionary to dict format

# Show the input and output
print("input_dict:", input_dict, type(input_dict))
print()
print("base64:", output_byte, type(output_byte))
print()
print("output_dict:", output_dict, type(output_dict))
```

[image]