# Converting request body to json Django Python

Tags: python, json, django

Below is a view in python Django and output it gives

Code

```
@csrf_exempt
def stk_push_callback(request):

    data = request.body
    print(data)

    got_data = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))

    result_code = got_data['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode']
    result_desc = got_data['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultDesc']

    print(' ')
    print('ResultCode: ', result_code)
    print(result_desc)
    print(' ')

    room = room_val()
    check_in = in_val()
    check_out = out_val()
    user = user_val()

    if result_code == 0:
        booking = book_room(user, room, check_in, check_out)
        print (booking)
    
        return render(request, 'booking/paymentcomplete.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'booking/paymenterror.html')
```

Output `print(data)`

```
b'{"Body":{"stkCallback":{"MerchantRequestID":"9088-17223944-1","CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_310520212138262746","ResultCode":1032,"ResultDesc":"Request cancelled by user"}}}'
```

How do i convert the output to json and also how do i access the `"ResultCode":1032` value for further processing? Regards.

Comment: what if you use `request.POST` or `request.GET` instead of `request.body`

Comment: The view is a callback url where an API is sending me POST json data

Answer (score 0):

I'm with phone and it's hard to explain more.

```
import json
data = request.body
data_dict = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8")) 
print(data_dict['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode'])
```

For more information check [How to convert bytes type to dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184578/how-to-convert-bytes-type-to-dictionary/53406072) answer.

Comment: Hello, I've tried this but it yields a JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: `print(request.POST)` and check it's type if your method is post. Reply it here let's continue debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually far from the solution.

`request.post` handles post data via an html form.

While `request.body` gives you a raw HTTP request body as a bytestring. You can convert into a dictionary using `json.loads()`.

I used `got_data = json.loads(data)` and it worked as expected.

`data` was converted to a Python dictionary and so you can do dict related operations on it,

`result_code = got_data['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode']`

[More detailed blog post here.](https://medium.com/@sampathkumar/how-to-read-json-data-in-an-http-post-request-in-django-d29fd6dae6b4)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `GET` method you can do this

**exm.html**

```
<input type="text" name="test1" >
```

**views.py**

```
test1 = request.GET["test1"]
dataJson = json.dumps({"test1":test1})
```

if you are using `POST` method
you can do this

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
import json

data = request.body
data = str(data, encoding='utf-8')
data = unquote(data)
data = json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `json()` method.

```
data = request.json()
```

Comment: Hi, that produces AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'json'

Comment: This is for python requests library. It can't be used for Django.